# Should summary be after each question?

Tags: audience

I am helping to rewrite an app that is written for quizzes. 
Our investors are sure that putting summary* after each question is necessary to keep audience attention. Sadly it is making the whole quiz time-consuming. (so making a quiz for 50 questions is almost impossible, because how much time it would take.)

I am thinking if the investors are really right about the audience, my intuition is telling me that we shouldn't show results after each question. Also, I not sure if it is needed for the participants of the quiz. They see if their answer is good on their own screens, and how it effect their group result.

*by summary I mean a screen that showing results of all participants and results for groups they are in. To rephrase it, the screen is showing how many points each participant/group score.

Comment: The wireframe doesn't really help understand what's going on here. If there are five questions in the quiz, how many screens would the user see? Can you describe the workflow in words? e.g. 1 - question, 2 - answer to question, 3 - etc

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what the summary summarizes: time that each individual person took to answer, with the correct answers highlighted?

Comment: Then I will delete the diagram, I've made it to illustrate why it takes so long, but I see it is taking you away from the main theme.

Comment: Doesn't the word "summary" already contradict using it after every question?

Comment: After each question summary is actualized. 

it looks like:
question -> answer -> who answered correctly -> summary (adding just collected points, showing how it is changing classifications) -> next question... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only way to know for sure is to test with users and survey them afterwards**

Stakeholders say yes to summaries, designer says no to summaries. Who is right? Personally I think your intuition is correct and showing summaries after every question in an effort to keep users interested is a big mistake, and will result in a slow and boring experience.

When you end up in a deadlock with stakeholders, when you feel like you know the right answer, but there's no article or publication you can point to, **you need to generate data to prove your case.**

This data will come from user testing. Test 2-3 versions. One version with summaries after each step. One version with summaries all at the end. (If you have the resources and enough users you might test another version where you **divide the questions into groups and show summaries after a small number of questions**)

After the tests, ask the participants questions with the aim of measuring their perceived experience e.g how easy/difficult, fast/slow, clear/complicated they thought it was.

Comment: I was thinking about testing, but I'm not sure If I can get an objective result. We want here to test audience respond, so to make it we would have to arrange the whole even for 50-100 people, right? I think audience respond would be different when they don't have any connection to any of participant, or/and when the audience is cut to like 5 people. I think the results of the test would be unreliable.

Comment: +1 for 'divide the questions into groups and show summaries after a small number of questions'

Comment: We mede the questionary on one of the minor events and then I learn how important it is to research. The audience wanted summary only when there is relevant change in classification. For the competitors seeing their own points and place wasn't enough, they wanted to see whole summary after each and every question. It ease their stress.